# Tinymce: Spellchecker is not working

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, wysiwyg, spell-checking

I am using `spellchecker` for `tinymce` in my application. The spellchecker internally using `Moxiecode.TinyMCE.dll`.

It was working fine before our last live update. Suddenly it's giving error saying `You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse`.

Here is the stacktrace which is appearing with the error detail in popup

System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6038604 Moxiecode.TinyMCE.SpellChecker.GoogleSpellChecker.SendRequest(String lang, String data) +762 Moxiecode.TinyMCE.SpellChecker.GoogleSpellChecker.CheckWords(String lang, String[] words) +197 Moxiecode.TinyMCE.SpellChecker.SpellCheckerModule.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +500 Moxiecode.TinyMCE.Web.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +282 System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +100 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75     
  **Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.504

I search for the resolution of error but didn't found any solution.

Can anyone suggest workaround for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had searched for the solution of issue, but there isn’t any problem with our application. Basically the point is, we are using a spell checker web service provided by Google with our WYSIWYG editor. I found that, from yesterday somehow the service not working properly or stopped by Google.

Here are some links which have some notes about user experiences

http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5793
http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=30779

Answer (score 0):

You CAN enable the browser's built-in spellchecker by doing the following:

```
tinymce.init({
    browser_spellcheck : true,
});
```

Be sure to remove spellchecker from your toolbar and your plugins list.

Comment: how it can be duplicate as I asked this question in Apr 2013... and what you posted was asked on sep 2013 :)

Comment: I don't think this works.  I had to use this snippet instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17921909/195835

Comment: Hey Simon - which browser are you working with? I only have to support the current line up, so maybe the snippet I posted doesn't play nice with older browsers?