# Is there any working spellchecker plugin for TinyMCE

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, spell-checking

I am using spellchecker from Google in my web application. It was working great but for some reason Google has stopped or removed their service and now it's not working. 
Here is the link for the SOAP API - https://developers.google.com/soap-search/?csw=1#1_3.

I tried with some other components like

1. http://www.jspell.com/tinymcespellchecker.html (it's require some intallation on the server and have some issues related to typing + some PHP code to execute)
2. http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/tinymce.html (it's require some PHP code to execute and giving error "the method is not allowed with "POST")

Both aren't working well as expected.

I had also posted an question previously but don't get any reply there [Tinymce: Spellchecker is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827971/tinymce-spellchecker-is-not-working).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why don't you use the browser spellchecking?
There is not much you will need to do to make it work.
The browser needs to have a dictionary of your language installed  (AddOn) and additionally you will need to set the attribute `spellcheck` of the editor body to `true`.

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) { //since tinymce4 use ed.on('init', function(evt){...
          ed.getBody().setAttribute('spellcheck', true);
      });
   }
});
```

This is far faster than a remote spellchecker approach (using something like Google spellchecker or an other aspell server).

Comment: There will be possibility that client doesn't installed any AddOn for the language, so it will not work in that case...

Comment: I'd say if the client want to use spellchecking he needs to install it. The other option is to maintain an own aspell/ispell server.

Comment: Thanks heaps.  This snippet works well to enable built-in spelling in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 10+.

Comment: @Thariama, Where i need to put this javascript?

Comment: @cracker: you need to set this in your tinymce init function (depends on how you initialize your editor)

Comment: returns "Unable to get property 'add' of undefined or null reference" for me

Comment: @gchq: the code needs to be adjusted to tinymce4 i guess (see the comment in the code above): use ed.on('init', function(evt){...

Comment: Not sure how I overlooked that! Thank you, works fine now and is certainly the best method I've come across so far :-)

Answer (score 14):

The spellchecker plugin included in the 4.XX download WILL NOT WORK. That plugin relied on Google's spell checking API which has been permanently discontinued, disabled, removed.  I too recommend using the browser-based spellchecker.  After that you can remove all code for spellchecker.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.mceEditor',
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    contextmenu: false,
});
```

Comment: For whatever reason, `contextmenu: false` fails to remove my context menu. And along the same line, the the browser's context menu with alternative word spellings does not come up. Any ideas?

Comment: Refer to the [TinyMCE browser-based spellchecker docs](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-docs/blob/master/get-started/spell-checking.md) and the [TinyMCE context menu plugin docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/contextmenu/)

Answer (score 1):

Following up on mcain66's post, I was able to rewrite the .Net handler to use Google's new API.

> [New dll and source code are here](http://www.modernsignal.com/uploads/blog/tinymce_package_dotnet.zip).

Note that I updated the target framework to 3.5 in order to use the `JavaScriptSerializer`.  I can't imagine many people are using older versions of .Net at this point anyway.

The new API requires an API key, but the one in mcain66's post is the same one used by my version of Google toolbar, so it appears that every install of the toolbar uses the same key.

Anyway, I don't know if this is a great long-term solution since it's still an undocumented and unsupported API, but I'm hoping it gets us by until everyone is using IE10+ and can rely on native browser spell checking.

---

Ref: [Post by dhammond member at TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=30779)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with the latest version (4). All I had to do was add the following to my init statement. Note the plugin method. I have it on the toolbar as well as it doesnt appear if its not working - good check!

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        menubar: false,
        plugins: "spellchecker",
        toolbar: "cut copy paste pastetext undo redo spellchecker | link unlink hr | bold italic underline | bullist numlist outdent indent blockquote | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify",
        statusbar: false
    });
```